# Sphinx и Yii2, как правильно задавать limit?

Tags: php, yii2, sphinx

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть следующий код:

```
public function search() {
    $this->load($this->searchParams);

    $query = new Query();

    $items = $query->from('news')
        ->match($this->query)
        ->orderBy(['date_added' => SORT_DESC])
        ->all();

    $items = array_column($items,'id');

    $query = News::find()
        ->where(['in', 'id', $items]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => false,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 15
        ]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

1. Правильно ли я работаю с sphinx? Я передаю ему запрос поиска, получаю массив id и делаю по ним выборку.
2. Как работать с limit у sphinx? Возвращает только 20 записей... Получать текущую страницу и считать исходя из количества элементов на странице?
3. Или со sphinx мне надо получать не только id? а полный обьем данных и передавать их в DataProvider?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1) Лучше установить лимиты и офсеты для запроса в sphinx, но если скорость отображения устраивает и не нужно оптимизировать, то можно оставить так.

2) Можно установить ->limit(-1) либо ->addOptions(['max_matches' => -1]), тогда вернёт все записи. Но есть нюанс их не может быть более чем 65535.

3) Можно в Sphinx добавить данные и выводить их не делая отдельный запрос в БД, для ускорения(оптимизации) вывода, но не нужно забывать что Sphinx это поисковый движок, а не замена текущей БД. И если скорость отображения данных в вашем варианте устраивает заказчика, то оставляйте как есть.